# Set two values in one cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I change the contrast on my site by clicking one of the two "a" links and change font-size by clicking one of the three "a" links.
I change the contrast by adding/removing a new class to/from the body.

**Question:** How to set present contrast and font-size in one cookie ?
              I want to also save changes when user change subsite...
              I'm using jquery-1.2.3...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contrast">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="first_contrast" class="con1">a</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="second_contrast" class="con2">b</a></li> 
</ul>        
</div>

<div id="font">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="one" class="fon1">c</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="two" class="fon2">d</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="three" class="fon3">e</a></li>  
</ul>        
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($.cookie('f')) {
    $('body').css('font-size', $.cookie('f')); 
}
if($.cookie('t')) {
    $('body').addClass($.cookie('t')); 
}
$('#one').click(function(){
    $('body').css('font-size', '60%');
    $.cookie('f','60%', { path: '/', expires: 10000 });
});
$('#two').click(function(){
    $('body').css('font-size', '72.5%');
    $.cookie('f','72.5%', { path: '/', expires: 10000 });
});
$('#three').click(function(){
    $('body').css('font-size', '85%');
    $.cookie('f','85%', { path: '/', expires: 10000 });
});
$('#first_contrast').click(function(){
    $('body').removeClass('highcon');
    $.cookie('t','main', { path: '/', expires: 10000 });
});
$('#second_contrast').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('highcon');
    $.cookie('t','highcon', { path: '/', expires: 10000 });     
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, next code is much more universal than to add separate event to each button.

Your Html should be like this:

```
<button data-size="80%" class="font-size">Font-size 80%</button>
<button data-contrast="bright" class="contrast">Contrast bright</button>
<button data-size="90%" class="font-size">Font-size 90%</button>
<button data-contrast="low" class="contrast">Contrast low</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
 // check for existing cookie on page load
 setCookieString();

    $('.font-size').on('click', function(){
        var fontSize = $(this).data('size');

        $('body').css('font-size', fontSize);
        setCookieString(fontSize);

    });

    $('.contrast').on('click', function(){
        var contrastLevel = $(this).data('contrast');

        $('body').addClass(contrastLevel);
        setCookieString(contrastLevel, 1);
    });

    function setCookieString(newVal, valueNumInCookie) {
        var cookie = $.cookie('siteSettings') || '';
        var cookieArr = cookie.split(';');

        // if there is no arguments then we need to get values from existing cookie.
        // Otherwise need to set new values
        if(!arguments.length) {
            $('body').css('font-size', cookieArr[0]);
            $('body').addClass(cookieArr[1]);
        }
        else {
            cookieArr[valueNumInCookie || 0] = newVal;

            $.cookie('siteSettings', cookieArr.join(';'), { path: '/', expires: 10000});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Денис Коноплин. I had separate event for each "a link", because every "a link" has a different image in my example. Can i create a view "a links" with same class (e.g. "font-size") and whith different images?

Comment: of course, just add some additional class to it.
for example:

<li><a href="#" class="font-size fon1">c</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="font-size fon2">d</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="font-size fon3">e</a></li>

Comment: @Денис Коноплин, your jQuery code doesn't work for me. Click() method not response when i call it by class name...

Comment: Hi @JacobRutka. What version of jQuery do you use?
Try to change this line  $('.contrast').click(function(){     to   $('.contrast').on('click', function(){     (I edited my first post with this changes)

Comment: If current version will not work - please give me your code - for example here: plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: @Денис Коноплин, plnkr.co/edit/LSogPeO04SBctYELRk8A?p=preview"

Comment: but you did not added additional class, you gave the same id on three elements. Check my code, there is no id attr. You should remove id attr from elements.
Also in your example there is no jQuery lib, you need to add it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85001/discussion-between-jacob-rutka-and-denys-konoplin).